# Does Kubernetes download Docker image automatically?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Does Kubernetes download Docker image automatically when i create a pod or should I use Docker pull manually to Download the image locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to run `docker pull` manually. The [pod definition](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/walkthrough/README.html#pod-definition) contains the image name to pull and Kubernetes will pull the image for you. You have several options in terms of defining how Kubernetes will decide to pull the image, using the `imagePullPolicy:` definition in your pod spec. Much of this is documented [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/images.html), but basically you can pull if the image is not present, pull always, never update (once the image is local). Hopefully that doc can get you started.